# Maximum Value - Analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis, optimization, analyticity, maximum-principle

I am having a hard time figuring out where to start and what results to use to address the following question:

> Suppose $f(z)$ is analytic in the unit disc $D=\{z:|z|<1\}$ and continuous in the corresponding closed disc $\overline{D}=\{z:|z|\leq 1\}$. Suppose also $\frac{f(z)}{z^{7}}$ can be extended to be analytic in all of $D$, including the origin. If $|f(z)|\leq 9$ in $\overline{D}$, what is the maximal value that $|f(0.2-0.5i)|$ can assume under these conditions?

For your information, I am reading E.B. Saff & A.D. Snider's *Fundamentals of Complex Analysis*.

Comment: Note that the only relevant part of $0.2-i 0.5$ is its modulus, and $f$ can be written as $f(x)=z^7 g(z)$ for some function $g$ analytic on $D$ and continuous on its closure.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, as $g(z)=z^{-7}f(z)$ is analytic, then
$$
\sup_{\lvert z\rvert\le 1}\lvert g(z) \rvert=\sup_{\lvert z\rvert\le 1}\lvert\,f(z) \rvert\le 9.
$$
Thus $\lvert\, f(z) \rvert\le9\lvert z \rvert^7$, and hence
$$
\lvert\,f(.2+.5i)\rvert\le 9\lvert.2+.5i\rvert^7.
$$
This value is achieved for $f(z)=9z^7$.